# Bash Script Permission denied & Bad Interpreter

Tags: shell-script, kali-linux, executable, shebang

I'm on a kali linux 64 bit.

I have created a python script which takes 2 arguments to start. I don't want to type out every time the exact same paths or search in the history of the commands I used in terminal. So I decided to create a simple script which calls the python script with its arguments.

```
#! /bin bash

python CreateDB.py ./WtfPath ./NoWtfPath/NewSystem/
```

It is the exact same command I would use in terminal. However, I get an error message when I try to execute the script file.

```
bash: ./wtf.sh: /bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

wtf.sh has executable rights.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a space instead of a forward slash here:

```
#! /bin bash
```

Should be:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

or simply

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(the first space is optional). 
The shebang (`#!`) should be followed by the path *to an executable*, which may be followed by [one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303128/how-to-use-multiple-arguments-with-a-shebang-i-e), e.g.,

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
```

In this case `/usr/bin/env` is the executable; see `man env` for details.

Just `/bin` refers to a directory.

Comment: You might want to get into the habit of using `#!/bin/sh` (instead of `#!/bin/bash`) unless you know that you are using `bash` features.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks for cleaning this up a bit.  WRT bash vs. sh, I was just following the pattern from the question (although my tendency is to only use `sh` when I know I'm *not* using bash features).

Comment: In Ubuntu terminal, `which bash` is helpful. That returns `/bin/bash`. At the top of my Bash script I add `#!/bin/bash`. Then when I want to run the Bash script, I enter `bash foo.sh`. So `which sh` is used the same way. `sh foo.sh`

Comment: @G-Man, in the workaday world there are an unfortunate number of people who don't *know* whether they are using Bash features or not.  In many cases it's preferable to have a script *not run at all* (because Bash is specified in the shebang but is missing) rather than run and do something unexpected (because `/bin/sh` is something other than Bash and there are unnoticed Bashisms in the script).  [See here.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250988/135943)

Answer (score 5):

It is worth noting that if the mountpoint on which your script resides has the 'noexec' attribute, then you can shebang all you want and it still won't work, but invoking the interpreter with the script as an argument will (so long as that in turn doesn't try to run another script on a noexec mount).

Comment: This is what did it for me. Just had to invoke the interpreter explicitly as said in this answer: `bash ./myscript.sh`