# bash bad interpreter and permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, perl

I installed RHEL 5.1 on a virtual machine. I would like to install VMware Tools, but I keep getting an error. I am performing the installation via the tar procedure. I get the following error:

```
bash: ./VMware-install.pl: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

The ./VMware-install.pl and /usr/bin/perl files have full rwx permissions, but I keep getting the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: First of all: 5.1 had end of support 5 years ago. *cough*  Did you by any chance install a 64-bit perl on a 32-bit OS?

Comment: I'd suggest running `ls -l /usr/bin/perl` so we can see the exact permissions... which should not be `rwxrwxrwx`.

Comment: The filesystem the `VMware-install.pl` files may have `noexec` permission. What directory is `VMware-install.pl` in? If it's `/tmp`, try copying all the stuff to a different directory.

Comment: Are you sure about the capitalization? That program's been named all-lowercase for as long as I've been using VMware products, which is an awfully long time.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: If the OP had the name of the Perl script wrong, the error message would have been `bash: ./VMware-install.pl: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @WarrenYoung If OP is running that file from a FAT or VFAT filesystem, that would explain everything...

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Or NTFS, or HFS+, or ISO9960, or UDF... (Some of those can be case-sensitive, but not as a default.)

Comment: Could be a DOS-style endline. You can try `/usr/bin/perl ./VMware-install.pl` .

Comment: I got the OS, perl, and program as a Kickstart package because this VM will be supporting a standalone Navy application. I did NOT select the OS.

Comment: As for the rwx of the perl, it has full rights across each category. How should the default settings for perl be set? As for the VMware-install.pl, it is located in the directory called vmware-tools-distrib. When I get back into work tomorrow, I will try the options listed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplify your situation:  This is not a VMware install problem, it's a "Why doesn't the system recognize /usr/bin/perl?" problem. Once that's fixed, you should be able to install VMware... at least, you've overcome the first hurdle.

So, try: `/usr/bin/perl -e 'print "Hello, world\n";'` and see what you get. This will be your first clue into the underlying problem.

If it works, try `/usr/bin/perl ./VMware-install.pl`

If it doesn't work, it's something weird and will probably take more investigation, such as what filesystem perl is located on and such.

But I'd start at zooming in on /usr/bin/perl.

Comment: The Hello World worked. When I performed the perl with the VMware install, it executed the script properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem, and the same error message.  In my case it was a permissions problem: The script lacked execution permision.

When I turned on execution permission on the script, it was solved in my case.  Like so:

```
$ chmod u+x ./VMware-install.pl
```

Comment: Can you tell me how my guess is incorrect?

Comment: OK, my bad. But I don't see why `/usr/bin/perl ./VMware-install.pl` worked.

Comment: I wrote my answer because I ran into a problem with this exact error message and landed on this page looking for a solution before I found it myself. I obviously didn't notice the remark about the permissions.

Comment: In that case, you did exactly the right thing by posting an answer as it wasn't a guess at all, but a working solution for encountering the same problem.  I've reversed my vote and deleted my previous comments.  Thanks for contributing to the site!

Answer (score 0):

Running `perl ./yourfile.pl` should work as Mike suggested.

It's probably a problem in the script calling `#!/usr/bin/perl` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env perl`

See [Bash Script Permission denied & Bad Interpreter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144347/bash-script-permission-denied-bad-interpreter) or `man env`