# evaluation of arithmetic expansion in bash

Tags: bash

The following line creates `file_c-6.txt` but outputs `5`:

```
$ i=5; ls file_a-${i}.txt file_b-${i}.txt > file_c-$(( ++i )).txt; echo $i
5
$ cat file_c-6.txt
file_a-5.txt
file_b-5.txt
```

If one removes `>` it would list `file_c-6.txt` and output `5`:

I can't understand why it doesn't keep the value of `i` in the first example.

```
$ i=5; ls file_a-${i}.txt file_b-${i}.txt file_c-$(( ++i )).txt; echo $i
file_a-5.txt  file_b-5.txt  file_c-6.txt
6
```

Comment: that's bizarre.

Comment: If I use `echo` instead of `ls`, it works the second way in both the cases.

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to the code example in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250988/135943).

Comment: `/bin/echo` preserves the difference, so it seems like output redirections for external commands happen in a subshell.

Comment: Definitely worth a bug report to bug-bash@gnu.org; it's not fixed in 4.4, currently under development.

Comment: Are you sure you're running bash? I tried it in bash (4.3), it works as expected (echo $i in the end returns 6). Though in `sh` it works exactly as in your example.

Comment: what if you remove the spaces between `((` and`++i` and `))`. maybe its nothing, but `bash`'s splitting on `<>` redirections is always screwy and non-standard anyway.

Comment: @rush Sure you didn't change anything? I'm using bash 4.3.30 on debian 8.2 and I'm getting the same results as Noil Noil in the question. I can also confirm choroba's findings using the bash builtin echo command. However, explicitly using `/bin/echo` yields the same result as described in the original question. So that seems to support the explaination offered by chepner.

Comment: It's bash: 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Comment: @mikeserv - removing spaces doesn't change anything and it's not a `bash`-only thing - I get the same behavior with `zsh 5.2`

Comment: @don_crissti - zsh doesnt expand the spaces to separate fields like bash. I think bash is the only shell in which you might have to quote a redirection target word against ifs splitting. So I was curious if it mattered. I didn't think it would.

Comment: @Wildcard The problem with dash in this case is that it doesn't understand `i++`, nor `++i`, but it process `++i` as a case of double `+i`. In dash, the file "written to" will be `5` as well as the value printed. Instead, zsh and bash will "write to" file `6` and print `5`. That proves that `++i` was interpreted as an increment but not kept in memory.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, I'm pretty good with shell scripting, but the only conclusion I take away from this discussion is: *Never use increment operators within arithmetic substitution*.  The variety of possible results is too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this under strace, you can see that the version that uses `ls` starts up the command in a subshell, where the version which uses echo executes it all in the existing shell.

Compare the output of

```
$ strace -f /bin/bash -o trace.txt -c 'i=5; echo $i; echo file_c-$((++i)).txt; echo $i'
5
6
6
```

against

```
strace -f /bin/bash -o trace.txt -c 'i=5; echo $i; ls > file_c-$((++i)).txt; echo $i'
5
5
```

You'll see in the first:

```
1251  execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "i=5; echo $i; echo file_c-$(( ++"...], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
...
1251  write(1, "5\n", 2)                = 2
1251  write(1, "file_c-6.txt\n", 13)    = 13
1251  write(1, "6\n", 2)                = 2
```

And in the second:

```
1258  execve("/bin/bash", ["/bin/bash", "-c", "i=5; echo $i; ls > file_c-$(( ++"...], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
...
1258  write(1, "5\n", 2)                = 2
...
1258  stat("/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=110080, ...}) = 0
1258  access("/bin/ls", R_OK)           = 0
1258  clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f7301f40a10) = 1259
1259  open("file_c-6.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
1259  dup2(3, 1)                        = 1
1259  close(3)                          = 0
1259  execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
1259  write(1, "71\nbin\nfile_a-5.txt\nfile_b-5.txt"..., 110) = 110
1259  close(1)                          = 0
1259  munmap(0x7f0e81c56000, 4096)      = 0
1259  close(2)                          = 0
1259  exit_group(0)                     = ?
1259  +++ exited with 0 +++
1258  <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 1259
1258  rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7301570d40}, {0x4438a0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f7301570d40}, 8) = 0
1258  rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
1258  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1259, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
1258  wait4(-1, 0x7ffd23d86e98, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
1258  rt_sigreturn()                    = 0
1258  write(1, "5\n", 2)                = 2
```

In this last example, you see the `clone` into a new process (from 1258 -> 1259), so now we're in a subprocess.  The opening of file_c-6.txt which means that we've evaluated `$((++i))` in the subshell, and the execution of `ls` with its stdout set to that file.

Finally, we see that the subprocess exits, we reap the child, then we continue with where we left off... with `$i` set to 5, and that's what we echo out again.

(Remember variable changes in a subprocess do not percolate up to the parent process, unless you do something explicitly in the parent to grab the child's changes)

Comment: Excellent analysis. One solution would be to use a temporary variable for the incremented value: `i=5; j=$(( i + 1 )); ls file_a-${i}.txt file_b-${i}.txt > file_c-${j}.txt; i=${j}; echo $i`.