# ./ does not work after chmod

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm on a Centos server and when I tried to run

`./script.sh`

I get the `Permission Denied` error even after I tried adding `chmod +x script.sh`.

`sh script.sh` works though.

**UPDATE**

The script file starts with `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: dos file might trigger end-of-line problem, have you tried `dos2unix script.sh` ?

Comment: Does your user have read permission on the script?

Comment: Is the script located on a partition mounted with `noexec`? Check with the `mount` command.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your script lacks a "shebang".  The system tries to read which interpreting program should be executed to run the script. A "shebang" is recognized by the system if it is on the very first line and starts with `#!`.

Examples:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

```
#!/bin/sh
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

```
#!/bin/sed
```

Note that `#!` is a comment otherwise in most scripting languages, so it will not error out if you run it with a specific interpreting program from the command line like so:

```
$ bash ./script.sh
```

More information:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: It has the line `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Does `/bin/sh` actually exist on your system? Is it a shell binary? Does  `/bin/sh` have executable (x) permission set?

Comment: What is the difference between a sh and bash hashbang?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Comment: @Sam, it runs a different shell. Not all systems have Bash, and even on those that do, `/bin/sh` might not be Bash (e.g. Debian and Ubuntu). See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/250913/170373

Comment: Also, AFAIK, the shell is supposed to try to interpret the script itself (or run `/bin/sh` on it) if there's no shebang, or rather, if `execve()` doesn't work on it. At least Linux gives `ENOEXEC` ("Exec format error") instead of `EACCESS` ("Permission denied") if the file isn't recognized as an executable, so the error message here doesn't really match that situation.